# Problems with migration

Tags: 7, migrations

I'm using the modules [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Drupal to Drupal Migration](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules to migrate some Drupal 7 content to another Drupal 7 site.

It works very well for users and their pictures; the nodes are migrated too with all the fields but the image field.

What data should I use for *[field_product_image:destination_dir]*, *[field_product_image:destination_file]*, and *[field_product_image:source_dir]*?

The image field is *field_product_image*. I have exported/imported the content types to the new Drupal 7 installation. The images are stored in *default/files/image/galerien*.

Comment: Did you migrated the files first?

Comment: no i just went through the wizard (m_d2d UI) and there i choosed all content what i want to migrate. It said"migrate files other than userpics" and i checked this option. At the end it migrates all data together.

Comment: Try reverting it again and migrate step by step. First files then roles, users, nodes in sequences.

Comment: Sadly i have the same problems. I migrate all files first and then migrate the nodes but still same problem: image-field is missing. For the userimages it works well but not for the images of the nodes

Comment: Oh yeah. Can I see your mapping of image field? I know what can be the issue.

Comment: the image-field is [field_product_image] but its completly unmapped. No entries for "sourcefield", "standard-value" and "source-migration"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22655/discussion-between-lolhonk-and-sumit-madan).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much Sumit Madan,

he gives me the solution:

Mapping:

for the file class of the image field enter this as "standard value": MigrateFileFid

set "TRUE" for preserve_files of your image-field.

thanks again!